# How to use Netbeans plugin?

Tags: plugins, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans 7.2.1 and I'm new to Java (but I program in C# for most of the time).
I recently downloaded, installed and activated a plugin (nbm file) from Java.net. I had been struggling on how to "Import" or "Package" it within my JFrame application in order for me to start writing the code.

Here is the link to download the plugin: http://java.net/projects/nbplugin-avr/downloads

Can some one please guide me on this, it is greatly different in C#.

Comment: have you installed the plugin ?

Comment: Yes, Installed and activated. None that I can see anything at the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plugins work on netbeans app. it adds functions to the netbeans IDE. plugins aren't classes you can import to your projects.

you should also check if that plugin is written for netbeans 6 or 7. netbeans 6 plugins dont work on netbeans 7

Comment: Ok. That is clear. I downloaded, installed and activated the plugin. But I don't see anything at the IDE.

Comment: @SimonOngsk you should also check if that plugin is written for netbeans 6 or 7. netbeans 6 plugins dont work on netbeans 7